# Prove that $\mid f(x)\mid \le 1 $ for almost all x.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

> Suppose $f$ is a real valued $L^1$ function on $\mathbb R$ such that for all measurable sets $E$, we have  $$\left| \int_E f(x)\ \mathsf d m \right| \le m(E) $$
>   where $m$ is Lebesgue measure. Prove that $| f(x)| \le 1$ for almost all x.

I tried to show it by contradiction, and I stuck could not come up with good ideas so I just wondering can anyone provide me hints.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** What can you say about 
$$E_n := \{ x | |f(x)| > 1 +\frac{1}{n} \}$$

Comment: I think En are increasing sequence of sets. right?

Comment: @user145993 what does the given relation tells you about their measure?

Comment: can you explain me little bit more.

Comment: @user145993 The limit of these $E_n$ is the set $E := \{x : |f(x)| >1\}$. But then we have $$m(E) \leq \int_{E} \leq m(E)$$, implying $m(E) = 0$ by a contradiction argument.

Comment: @user145993 Split $f$ into the positive and negative part. WLOG $f \geq 0$. Then $\int_{E_n} f(x) \geq (1+\frac{1}{n}) m(E_n)$ which implies that $m(E_n)=0$. And $E = \cup_{n} E_n$ is countable union of measure zero sets.....

Comment: Yea I got it I appreciated all your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

As $f\in L^1$, we have the induced signed measure $\nu(E)= \int_E f\ \mathsf dm$, and by hypothesis, $|\nu(E)|\leqslant m(E)$ for all measurable sets $E$. By the Jordan decomposition, $\nu = \nu^+ - \nu^-$ where $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ are finite positive measures, and $|\nu|$, the total variation of $\nu$, is defined by $|\nu|=\nu^+ + \nu^-$. So if there were a set of positive measure $E$ on which $f>1$, this would imply $\nu(E)>0$, so $\nu^+(E)>\nu^-(E)$. But $|\nu(E)|\leqslant m(E)$, which yields $\nu^+(E)+\nu^-(E)\leqslant m(E)$, and hence $\nu^+(E) \leqslant m(E)-\nu^-(E)$, a contradiction.